# Using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ITemplate to draw cutom lines

Tags: arcobjects, mapcontrol

I am using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ITemplate to draw custom lines such as dot/dash lines on a map control.

Then, I used the below code:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ITemplate templateCls = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.TemplateClass();
templateCls.Interval = 1;
templateCls.AddPatternElement(1, 3);
```

The below image 1 will show the result for this.

[image]

But, I am want to the line include round elements (not rectangle) as the below image 2.

[image]

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a MarkerLineSymbol with a round marker to accomplish this.  I can't tell from the code snippet you provided, but I suspect you're using a CartographicLineSymbol and that will only give you line dashes.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Yes, I used CartographicLineSymbol. Could you please show some codes for demo this

Comment: It's the exact same code youi have above but just set on a MarkerLineSymbol with a SimpleMarker of type circle as the marker.

Comment: Hi Craig, when I use SimpleMarker (SimpleMarkerSymbolClass), I don't see the "Style" property, I only see other properties: Angle, Color, Size, XOffset, YOffset,... I don't know why ?

Comment: See the Style property on the interface ISimpleMarkerSymbol.